# simple [pythonic] way to create ids for a given set of words

Tags: python, performance

I have a large corpus of texts on which I want to run a couple of algorithms. These algorithms do not care about what a word is - a word is just a unique object to them. Hence I want to reduce the size of the text by simply replacing the words with integer IDs.

An example:

```
my_string = "an example sentence with an example repetition."
my_ids = get_ids_from_string(my_string)
print my_ids
>>> [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 4] ### note that the ID for 'example' is always the same
```

I am looking for a neat, efficient, pythonic way of solving this.

Comment: What tools will you use for those algorithms? Almost all of the established NLP libraries come with some sort of preprocessing utilities, so it may be worth using them.

Comment: how much data are you going to be working with? can you fit the corpus in memory?

Comment: I am building a neural network. The current implementation just thinks about the words as features - giving my one giant feature-vector(one entry per unique word). The 6 million records fit into my macbook ram, and my current dev-server has 2TB, but eventually that will not be enough to keep all documents in memory, hence there needs to be some kind of compression happening. Furthermore, this will be an online network (meaning, it will continuously learn)

Comment: Do you see yourself needing a database sooner than later? Each word's id is going to need to be stored permanently for lookup, is that right? If so, there will need to be database queries being made somewhere along the line which is going to slow things down a lot.

Comment: The resulting lookup-dictionary is extremely small in size and can be stored even in a text-file (due to the properties of natural language). I am working a lot with in-memory databases, but I do not see this as a use-case for one. The overhead would be too big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that I came up with is the following(you can re-use the next_i-function for multiple id-generators):

```
from collections import defaultdict

COUNTER = defaultdict(lambda : -1)
def next_i(counter_id=0):
    """Return a new ID"""
    global COUNTER
    COUNTER[counter_id] += 1
    return COUNTER[counter_id]

id_generator = defaultdict(lambda : next_i(0))

my_string = "an example sentence with an example repetition."
my_ids = [id_generator[t] for t in my_string.lower().split()]
print my_ids
>>> [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 4]
```

On my **6 million document** setup this algorithm finishes in **45.56s**.

Answer (score 2):

You're not winning much by replacing strings with integers --- you'd win just as much by making sure that identical strings are stored only once in memory.

```
my_string = "an example sentence with an example repetition."
words = my_string.split()
unique_words = [intern(word) for word in words]
```

The "unique_words" list is equal to the "words" list, but `intern()` guarantees that the strings will be used once.  If you do this on a large corpus of text with a much smaller set of possible words, it will not use substantially more memory than integers.

Comment: Can use `id(intern(word))` if numbers are still needed

Comment: Thank you Armin, I did not know the what the ```intern``` function does. Unfortunately it does not solve my exact use-case, where I am creating an input-vector for a neural network (hence the integer mapping).

Comment: @xndrme: `id(intern(word))` doesn't work reliably: `intern()` returns the same string object as it previously did, but only if it still exists.  If you take the `id()`, the old version will likely be gone and the next time a different string object will be returned (with a different id).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the `fromkeys` method of a `collections.OrderedDict`:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> my_string = "an example sentence with an example repetition."
>>> words = my_string.split()
>>> code = {w: i for i,w in enumerate(OrderedDict.fromkeys(words))}
>>> [code[w] for w in words]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 4]
```

This works because `OrderedDict.fromkeys` will make a dictionary containing unique words in the order they were first seen:

```
>>> OrderedDict.fromkeys(words)
OrderedDict([('an', None), ('example', None), ('sentence', None), ('with', None), ('repetition.', None)])
```

---

Since that works but apparently doesn't perform very well, maybe:

```
from itertools import count
counter = count()
code = {}
coded = [code[w] if w in code else code.setdefault(w, next(counter)) for w in words]
```

Comment: I would use the `re` module to split on whitespace and punctuation, as `repetition.` is counted as a word.

Comment: @C.B. if we care about that, we should be using `nltk` or something to do the splitting.  That's orthogonal to the id creation, though.

Comment: Thank you for your post! I ran your code, but unfortunately in its current form it is much slower on even my small setup(6 million documents). my solution finishes in **45.56s**, while yours took **247.49s**.

Comment: @marco: that's disappointing; it's always annoying when the "clean" solution doesn't perform very well.

Comment: I still like your solution because it is very concise, but I cannot use it in its current form - I will check if I can speed it up a bit

Answer (score 0):

We have a corpus (about a million documents) that we produce recommendations from for my company so size reduction is very important to us. The biggest gains in space reduction we get are from doing three simple things, two of them using [nltk](http://nltk.org/book/):

- Use the default [punkt sentence tokenization](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn-/trunk/doc/howto/tokenize.html) to reduce the sentences to more meaningful symbols.
- Remove all [stopwords](http://www.ranks.nl/resources/stopwords.html) as they don't contain any useful information.
- Stem the words using the [nltk porter stemmer](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/stem.html).

This is not the most processor-efficient way to do this but will be pretty efficient in terms of space if that is your bottleneck. If the sentence tokenizer is too slow (I think it's the slowest part), it would still probably be worth it to do the stemming and remove the stopwords.

Comment: Thanks for the post! I have been playing around with nltk a lot. While it is an extremely great tool to work with its not fast enough for the operations that I need, which is why I implement the algorithms that I need myself.

Comment: Yeah that's totally understandable. About how many documents / second will you need to process and how big is each one?

Comment: Since this is an experimental setup there are no quotas, yet. The purpose is to build is as fast as possible, so we can test different network structures and let them compete against each other. The current *big* test-corpus has more than 650 million documents. The documents have dramatically different sizes(as short as 5 words and as long as 10k words)

Comment: Cool. For your situation, I would consider doing one run over all documents that stems and removes stopwords then replaces all of the words with their integer ids. After that, you will have a pre-processed corpus that the networks use to compete against one another. That way you only have to do a single run of space-reduction that can be used for whatever test.

Comment: That would be a perfect solution if we had a final set of pre-processing steps. However, we are training many different neural networks and have to re-run the algorithm many times, to find the perfect combination of pre-processing steps. Hence I am looking for a fast algorithm.

Comment: Can you help me understand why the words -> integer step needs to happen more than once for each document? That is usually the first step of a pre-processor and only ever needs to happen a single time. Furthermore, since your dataset is small enough to fit in laptop memory, it seems like a one-time performance hit on the tokenization  in order to get a higher-quality working data set might be worth it. This sounds like an interesting problem your working on, if you want to talk about it more, hit me up and I'd be happy to.